# When to "Save" in App Update in iOS

Tags: ios

Concern is at what stage to "Save" when updating app with a new version for iOS in iTunes Connect. Changes have to be approved by another at admin level before going "live."  After changes to metadata and commenting in "Notes" section, should one click "Save," just to keep changes for another admin to see or will this take it lve? I would not make changes to the live version because I understand that WILL change the live version. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are in `<version_number> Prepare for Submission`, you can click save as many times as you want. The changes won't be seen by the public until you submit for review and then release the app.